# New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form Powershell Console Widget

Tags: powershell, winforms, getcontent

Apologies if the answer is out there but I have been searching and maybe just not putting the right wordage in my searches.

I have a Windows Form that I have added checkboxes etc to. I have a <kbd>Go</kbd> button that when I click it I want to have a section on the Form display the output for

```
Get-Content MyLog.txt -Wait
```

So, I click <kbd>Go</kbd> and it will display that log file contents and as more data is added to that file it continues to scroll. Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: I dont see why not, can you share the code from the form? You might not be applying the feedback correctly.

Comment: The `-Wait` on that may be problematic. Maybe get the data, and setup a file watcher on that file to monitor for changes and then reload it when the file is updated. Otherwise I think your form is going to lock up and stop responding.

Comment: It might be possible to run `-Wait` on another thread so that the form doesn't freeze as @TheMadTechnician pointed out. But a file watcher definitely makes more sense

Comment: Another way to tackle this is to setup a (forms) [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) and poll the file so now and than (starting with modified date).

Comment: VasilNikolov I have no problem sharing my code. I will put it on github this weekend and post a link.
TheMadTechnician thanks, it doesn't have to be a -wait, I basically want it to as the service starts up I can see on the GUI the log file changing. What is a "file watcher"? I am not a developer but can code stuff that works. I am fine with RTFM so if you can point me to what to rad up on that would be great ;)
SantiagoSquarzon I can look into the "file watcher" but I don't knwo what that is. Can you point me in the right direction of what to research?

Comment: Code is now in github
https://github.com/PaulWebber/ServiceExecuteHelper